# Numerical integration gives very different result from analytical expression

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute some thermal-averaged integral as defined in [this reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09956.pdf). For the sake of the discussion, let's assume that the average of a quantity `X` looks like:

[image]

where `M` and `T` are parameters. Using [Cubature](https://github.com/stevengj/cubature), a simple C-package for adaptive multidimensional integration, I was able to implement these integrals.

The simplest case, `X(k)=1`, has the following analytical approximation I want to cross-check with my numerical integration:

[image]

where `K2` is a modified Bessel function. `Mathematica` corroborated the approximation. The implementation of these numerical integrals (see below) seem to work well for dummy examples:

```
./main_nNeq 30 100
0.3 | 1.77268e+06 | 1.95712e+06
```

but my actual code would require very extreme values, where both values are quite different:

```
/main_nNeq 1e12 7.11258e17
1.40596e-06 | 4.92814e+46 | 7.19634e+53
```

**Question:** What could be the underlying issue here? Thanks!

---

My code (written in C++ for no particula reason) looks like this:

```
//
// COMPILING INSTRUCTIONS: 
// g++ -o main_nNeq nNeq.cpp cubature-master/hcubature.c -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas -lgmp -std=c++11
//
// MORE INFO: http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature_(Multi-dimensional_integration)
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include "cubature-master/cubature.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_dilog.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>


using namespace std;


#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x)) //x^2
#define CUB(x) ((x)*(x)*(x)) //x^3
#define K1(x) (boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(1.0, x)) //BesselK(1, x)
#define K2(x) (boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(2.0, x)) //BesselK(2, x)

//Momentum grid
const double log_kmin = -2;
const double log_kmax = 25;
const int Ngrid = 2000;

//Numerical constants
const double gw = 2.0;
const double PI = M_PI;
const double a_int = 0.0;

//Cosmological parameters
const double g_star = 106.75;
const double Mpl = 1.22e19; //GeV
const double aR = Mpl/2.0*sqrt(45.0/CUB(PI)/g_star); //as in Eq. (83), arXiv:1812.02651
const double Tcom = aR;
#define aa(eta) (aR*eta) //as in Eq. (82), arXiv:1812.02651


//f_F
double f_F(long double k, long double T, long double M){
    long double root = SQR(k) + SQR(M);
    root = isinf(root) ? k : sqrt(root);
    long double expo = exp(root/T);
    return isinf(expo) ? 0.0 : 1.0/(expo+1.0);
}

//n_N_eq
long double n_N_eq(double T, double M){
    return SQR(M)*T*K2(M/T);
}

//integrand
double integrand__n_N_eq(double k, double T, double M){
    return SQR(k)*f_F(k, T, M);
}

//integrator
struct fparams {
    double M;
    double T;
};

//function to be integrated
int inf_n_N_eq(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval){
    struct fparams * fp = (struct fparams *)fdata;
    //(void)(dim); /* avoid unused parameter warnings */
    //(void)(params);
    double M = fp->M;
    double T = fp->T;
    double t = x[0]; 
    double aux = integrand__n_N_eq(a_int+t*pow(1.0-t, -1.0), T, M)*pow(1.0-t, -2.0);
    if (!isnan(aux) && !isinf(aux))
    {
        fval[0] = aux;
    }
    else
    {
        fval[0] = 0.0;
    }
    return 0;
}





int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Defining variables (M, T)
    double M = stof(argv[1]); //command line argument
    double T = stof(argv[2]); //command line argument

    //range integration 1D
    double xl[1] = { 0 };
    double xu[1] = { 1 };

    double nNeq, nNeq_ERR;

    struct fparams params_nNeq = {M, T};
    hcubature(1, inf_n_N_eq, &params_nNeq, 1, xl, xu, 0, 0, 1e-4, ERROR_INDIVIDUAL, &nNeq, &nNeq_ERR);
    
    cout << M/T << " | " << nNeq << " | " << n_N_eq(T, M) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For better type-safety, you should implement your square and cube as "inline" functions.  For example, I could do `SQR("Hamburger")`, which kind of doesn't make sense, but the macros allow it.  An inline function would block it.  Or you could just substitute `x * x` in your code.

Comment: I highly recommend using `const` everywhere that variables are not modified after declaration.  For example: `const long double expo = exp(root/t);`.  This allows the compiler to make improved optimizations (such as better register usage).

Comment: Prefer to pass by reference instead of passing by pointer.  Pointers can point to anywhere and there is no practical method to detect an invalid pointer.  References "point" or refer to existing objects.

Comment: Don't define `void *` for the parameters.  Actually use the `fparams` type.  Pass by reference if you want to avoid the compiler from making copies; pass by `const` reference if the parameter is not modified.

Comment: Use `std::set_precision` when outputting to get a more accurate output.  Be aware of rounding to less digits of precision.

Comment: Keep all the types in the same units.  For example, `n_N_eq` returns a `long double`, whereas `f_F` returns a `double`.  On your platform, if `long double` and `double` are not the same precision, you may have some issues.  Remember that floating point is an approximation; so `long double` may have a better approximation than `double`.  And you may loose precision when converting between `double` and `long double`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are doing, since it is a long bit of code. I would, however, try to change variable of integration so that the limits would be finite (typically from (0,\infty) to (0,1) or (-1,1)).